# manually lower exception in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is there a way to lower the exception to execute the rest of the try statement before exception is hit and the program exits?

```
while(True):
    try:
        do something 1
        error occurs here
        do something 2
    except error as e:
         if(iteration == 2):
             iteration += 1
             # here I want to go back to do something 2 instead of exit()
         exit()
```

Comment: why not catch the exception in `error occurs here` with a proper `except` statement and `do something 2` in there. and you have more options: lookup  `try/except/else/finally` https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0341/ .

Comment: what error will  `do something 1` and   `do something 2` throw?

Comment: I can't add do something 2 inside error exception handler because it itself can cause the error

Comment: What are the do somethings?

Answer (score 2):

[The try statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> If finally is present, it specifies a ‘cleanup’ handler. The try clause is executed, including any except and else clauses. If an exception occurs in any of the clauses and is not handled, the exception is temporarily saved. The finally clause is executed. If there is a saved exception, it is re-raised at the end of the finally clause. If the finally clause raises another exception or executes a return or break statement, the saved exception is discarded:

```
def f():
    try:
        1/0
    finally:
        return 42

>>> f()
42
```

Comment: Thanks for your first answer on SO.  Please note the following for code formatting: single words with a single back-tick and use 4-space indenting for blocks (rather than <code> tag).  The `{}` icon in the formatting bar can assist.

Answer (score 0):

Your code format is a little off. Try the following

```
iteration = 0

while True:
    try:
        print(a) # this will cause an error since a isn't defined
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e)) # this will tell you what the error is
        iteration += 1
        if iteration <= 2:
            iteration += 1
            print(iteration) # just to check if code works , you can remove later
            # here I want to go back to do something 2 instead of exit()
        else:
            exit()
```

This will run the code twice, hence `if iteration <= 2` then exits when `iteration == 3`.

Comment: Catch exception as suggested above, keep your code 1 and code 2, or at least code 2, in separate function(s) as they are repeatable code. That will also help you avoid too much indented blocks after iteration checks or flag checks. (unless you need every bit of performance speed you can get)

Answer (score 0):

Either check the specific exception to see if the first function caused the error or set a flag:

```
flag = False
while True:
    try:
        do something 1
        error occurs here
        flag = True
        do something 2
    except error as e:
         if not flag:
            do something 
            exit()
    flag  = False
```

If  `do something 1` caused the error the flag  will be still False, if it were the second then the flag will be set to True.

If only the first can error then simply  just `do something 2` in the except:

```
while True:
    try:
        do something 1
        error occurs here
        do something 2
    except error as e:
            do something 2
            exit()
```